# Openpyxl формула в Excel нераспознанный текст

Tags: python, openpyxl

Python
Openpyxl
При отправке в Excel любой формулы вида:
Sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).value='=КОРЕНЬ(4)'
Формула не расчитывается. Висит ошибка распознавания текста. Если просто встать на формулу и прожать enter, то формула просчитывается.
Как побороть данный момент?
Конкретно формулу =ОКРУГЛ(A1;1)

Comment: ЕМНИП Openpyxl поддерживает формулы только на английском

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть решение. Проблема в кодировке.
Если банально делаю открытие файла с готовой формулой и начинаю ее дробить, то результат  получается.
К примеру, формула в ячейке A1:
=ОКРУГЛ(4;0)
Делим ее на две части и пишем результат в ячейку A2:
Sheet.cell(row=2,column=1).value='%s%s%s'%(Sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).value[:-4],16,sheet.cell(row=1,column=1).value[-3:])

То тогда результат будет. Но это неудобно. Есть другие идеи?

Comment: Ответ на свой же вопрос. Происходит удивительная конвертация при работе с русским excel!

Comment: Формулу в python нужно записывать на английском аналогом русской формуле, а сам excel автоматически конвертирует обратно. Итого: вместо =ОКРУГЛ(4;0), пишем =ROUND(4,0), но в excel все равно получится =ОКРУГЛ(4;0)

Comment: Какие существуют аналоги формул с русского на английский информации в интернете предостаточно. Но можно и самому получить результат, собственно как получилось у меня. Прочитать ячейку с русской формулой в питоне и вывести ее. Как вы заметите, она автоматически сконвертируется с русского в английский аналог. Кстати, это говорит о том, что excel хранит формулы в латинице, даже если они на нашем языке